# dropbox different in Ubuntu and Fedora

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, dropbox

The dropbox that I installed on Ubuntu 18.04 (nautilus-dropbox) runs a daemon and creates a dropbox folder under my home directory.  I would like to install dropbox on a fedora VM that works similarly.  Instead, I get some web-like app from which every file must be explicitly downloaded.  I don't want it to work this way.  Is there something like nautilus-dropbox available for Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

`nautilus-dropbox` is available from [RPM Fusion](https://rpmfusion.org/), specifically the non-free repos.